# Postfix logs to different socket

Tags: postfix, logging

Postfix allow in therir configuration the option "syslog_facility" wich permit change the facility from the default "mail".

But, is it possible to change the default socket "/var/spool/postfix/dev/log" or "/dev/log" to other destination?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any [configuration parameter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) for that. Neither is there any possible need to change it.

You should read [What you need to know about Postfix logging?](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#syslog_howto). By default Postfix lets `syslogd` do the job.

> Postfix daemon processes run in the background, and log problems and
>   normal activity to the syslog daemon. The `syslogd` process sorts events
>   by class and severity, and appends them to logfiles.

The `/var/spool/postfix/dev/log` is only needed if you run Postfix [chrooted](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#chroot_setup):

> Note that a chrooted daemon resolves all filenames relative to the
>   Postfix queue directory (`/var/spool/postfix`).
>
> Additionally, you almost certainly need to configure `syslogd` so that
>   it listens on a socket inside the Postfix queue directory. Examples of
>   `syslogd` command line options that achieve this for specific systems:
>
> - FreeBSD: `syslogd -l /var/spool/postfix/var/run/log`
> - Linux, OpenBSD:
>     `syslogd -a /var/spool/postfix/dev/log`

The queue directory can be changed:

> [`queue_directory`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#queue_directory) (default: see `postconf -d` output)
>
> The location of
>   the Postfix top-level queue directory. This is the root directory of
>   Postfix daemon processes that run chrooted.